# WooCommerce - changing dropdown list to text-input

Tags: woocommerce, real-time

i'm searching a way to convert dropdown list in WooCommerce into text-input field. I added hundreds of variation for width and height and now my client ask me to change it to input ;/ I need create something like this:
1st variation: if width = 20cm to 40cm AND height = 40cm to 90cm then price=myValue
And my products are in different price cathegory,so i have hundreds of variation for each group
Should i use csv pricing table? or something else than woocommerce ?

Comment: Have you seen the [Measurement Price Calculator](http://www.woothemes.com/products/measurement-price-calculator/)?

Comment: Yes, i know this plugin, its not free, and i have 6 different price cathegory > i need set the price of product like this : if product_name=x and width=y and height=z then price=myValue,for each variation width and height are values beetween 40-220cm(for example)

Comment: It isn't free, but it is significantly less expensive than what you'd pay a developer to custom code you a solution from scratch.

Comment: but my code is already working, when i select width and height from dropdown list, the price is changing how i want, the only thing i want to change is convert dropdown to text-input,and now i need to buy new plugin,and write 6 price-tables again? its a hundreds of variation for each table...

Comment: Well you didn't mention that in your question, so it seemed like you wanted someone to write this all for you. If you will edit your question to post your code and clarify where exactly you are struggling we might be able to help.